# XSLT transforming to table

Tags: xml, html-table

Is there any way to output elements in a for loop in XML?

```
<table>    
<tr>
<td><element1></td>
<td><element2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><element3></td>
<td><element4></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Is that your input or your output? And what part of the problem are you having trouble with? At first sight, you are doing what every XSLT tutorial covers in its first page. Please think more carefully about your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question "*Is there any way to output elements in a for loop in XML*?" is not really clear. The short answer is: No, there is no loop in XML.

But because of the title *"XSLT transforming to table"* I assume you are asking for a loop in xlst. The answer is: Yes, you can use `<xsl:for-each select="XML ELEMENT">` or even better in most cases `<xsl:template match="XML ELEMENT" >`shut do.